# Does Redis reset expiration time

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using `client.setex()` to create a Redis cache with an expiration time of say 3600 seconds but I also update it from time to time, and for that I am using `client.set()`.
Wondering if the expiration time stays the same or gets extended by 3600 every time I update that cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**set()** will remove the existing expiration time in Redis .

you can use :

```
client.set(key,value, "EX", client.ttl(key))
```

for continuing the expiration time.

for more detail :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21897851/5677187